# Populate one DropDown List from another selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two drop down list and I've populate them like this :

```
 private List<Client> Client()
        {
            var allClients= _db.tboClient.Select(x =>
            new Tecnico
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Nome = x.Nome
            }).ToList();
            return allClients;
        }

        private List<Pricerice> Price()
        {
            var allPrice = _db.tboPrice.Select(x =>
            new Cliente
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Nome_azienda = x.Nome_azienda
            }).ToList();
            return allPrice ;
        }
```

And then some methods that I recall `Client()` and `Price()`. I load the *View* like this :

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Price= Pricei();
    ViewBag.Clienti = CLienti();
    return View();
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CLienti, new SelectList(ViewBag.CLienti, "Id", "Nome_azienda"), new { @id = "ddlCLienti", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
 </div>

 <div class="dropdown">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Price, new SelectList(ViewBag.Price, "Id", "Nome"), new { @id = "ddlClienti", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
</div>
```

I want to populate the second(Price) drop down list based on the value selected from the first drop down list.

Comment: Please note that you set same id "**ddlClienti**" for two dropdowns, the second one might be "**ddlPrice**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to populate the second(Price) drop down list based on the value selected from the first drop down list.

To achieve above requirement of implement a cascading dropdown, you can try to populate the second dropdown based on the previous selection of the first dropdown on "ddlCLienti" dorpdown `change` event, like below.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("select#ddlCLienti").change(function () {
            var CLienti = $(this).val();

            $("select#ddlPrice").empty();

            $.getJSON(`/your_controller_name_here/GetPriceBySelectedCLienti?CLienti=${CLienti}`, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("select#ddlPrice").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.nome}</option>`);
                });
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

*`GetPriceBySelectedCLienti` action method*

```
public List<Price> GetPriceBySelectedCLienti(int CLienti)
{
    //query data based on selected CLienti

    //...
```